# Scan network for writable shares

Tags: windows, security, file-sharing

I have a small-business network with 30 Windows XP machines on a single subnet and in a simple workgroup, not a domain.  I would like to put a process in place that scans the network for writable shares.  There is only one machine on the network, the file server, that should allow write-access.  If there are any other machines that open up I would like to find out about it.

I intend to run the scan daily.  I have a Ubuntu machine running Nagios on the network already so the solution could be run from a Windows or Linux environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[SoftPerfect Network Scanner](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/)** does that (and more):

> Pings computers.
>
> Does not require administrative
>   privileges.
>
> Detects hardware (MAC) addresses even
>   across routers.
>
> **Detects** hidden shared folders (normally invisible on the network)
>   and **write accessible shares**.
>
> Detects your internal and external IP
>   addresses.
>
> Scans for listening TCP ports and SNMP
>   services.
>
> Retrieves currently logged-on users.
>
> You can mount and explore network
>   resources.
>
> Can launch external third party
>   applications.
>
> Exports results to HTML, XML, CSV and
>   TXT
>
> Supports Wake-On-LAN, remote shutdown
>   and sending network messages.
>
> Retrieves potentially any information
>   via WMI.
>
> Retrieves information from remote
>   registry.

[image]

*SoftPerfect Network Scanner is freeware and portable (does not have to be installed).*

Comment: you're more than welcome.