# How can I scan the local network for connected devices in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, mac, networking, printer, network-shares

I'm basically looking for [something like this](https://superuser.com/q/79990/167207) but available on Mac. I am using Mac OS X 10.6.

I am trying to connect a new workstation to our wireless multifunction printer and I'm having a hell of a time getting the device to spit out an IP for me to connect to.

Is there a way I can *scan* the network somehow?

Answer (score 241, accepted):

1. Ping the broadcast address.
   (You can find it with `ifconfig | grep broadcast`.)
2. And then do an `arp -a`.

Comment: Best answer because it required no software download. Thanks, NSD :)

Comment: Great tip.. I filtered out the results to only show the ip's that are not incomplete (and are present) with..


`arp -a | grep :`

Comment: Can someone explain why/how this works? You ping the broadcast and this causes all the other connected clients to commit network activity which is then visible to arp ??

Comment: Best answer.  You can do it one line too: ifconfig | grep broadcast | arp -a

Comment: @deweydb when you're on LAN, connecting to an IP involves resolving the IP into a mac address. ARP keeps a cache of all resolved IP addresses. Doing a broadcast ping indirectly triggers a resolution for all IPs on the network.
Now... how can we resolve the list of IPs into DNS (or other) names?

Comment: I use:  `arp -a | grep -v '^?' ` under Macosx.

Comment: What do the `? (192.168.1.15) at <incomplete> on eth0` mean? there is nothing (and AFAIK there has never been) anything on my lan at that address

Comment: oneliner: `ping $(ifconfig | grep broadcast | awk '{print $NF}') -t 1 > /dev/null && arp -a` (to have this work on a linux box you'll need to add `-b` to ping)

Answer (score 9):

Where x.x.x is the first three numbers in your ip address.

```
for ip in $(seq 1 254); do ping -c 1 x.x.x.$ip -o ConnectTimeout=5; [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "x.x.x.$ip UP" || : ; done
```

Comment: On a Mac here, had to slightly adjust your answer as the timeout is set using the ``-t`` option (for instance ``-t 5`` for a 5 seconds timeout)

Comment: Right, that also didn't work for me.  On the Mac you not only need to use the -t 5 option, but also move it to be before the ip. i.e. -c 1 -t 5 x.x.x.$ip.  Otherwise it'll error and bomb out.

Comment: Right. First of all, `x.x.x` only works for [netmasks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#IPv4_CIDR_blocks) that are `/24`(=`0xffffff00`). One should verify this using `ifconfig`. Second of all, this takes [21 minutes](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5+*+254+seconds) to run serially. Can do this in parallel by terminating the `for` loop using `&` instead of `;`. On MacOS, this looks like: `for ip in $(seq 1 254); do ping -c 1 -t5 192.168.1.$ip > /dev/null ; [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "x.x.x.$ip UP" || : & done`

Answer (score 8):

Single Line Answer: http://nmap.org/download.html [Use NMAP] or [Angry IP Scanner](http://angryip.org/)

Comment: The Angry IP Scanner  download link has changed. Better just to use the domain address: http://angryip.org

Answer (score 5):

Your printer provides a file share for dropping files into or are you just trying to locate the printer on your network?

Does your new multifunction printer support Bonjour/ZeroConf?  (Most new network based printers do) If so you can use a program such as [Bonjour Browser](http://www.tildesoft.com/Programs.html) to see what is available on your network.

On your router does it appear on the DHCP Clients Table (you may have to consult your manual to see how to see this table) - as this will also give you the IP but will also let you know for certain that your printer is actually connected to your network.

From your Mac itself you can use a program such as [Nmap](http://nmap.org) from the command line or use a GUI based app (eg. [Zenmap - GUI for Nmap](http://nmap.org/zenmap/) or [AngryIPScanner](http://www.angryip.org)) to scan your network and then see what ports are available.

Comment: To add to @Chealion's answer, if your printer supports Bonjour, you should see it in the "Nearby printers" list on the "Printer" pop-up menu of the "File > Print..." dialog sheet, or in the printer browser you see when you go to "Add Printer...".

So many multifuction printers from the major manufacturers support Bonjour nowadays, that I'm surprised when a printer doesn't just automatically show up on those places I mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

`NMAP` [nmap] is your best friend for all sorts of network devices scans. Use `Zenmap` if you need GUI [zenmap].

Assuming your local network is `192.168.0.0/24` (where `24` means netmask `255.255.255.0`) this will give you online hosts with their IP and MAC addresses:

`nmap -sP 192.168.0.0/24`

You can download the package from project website or build yourself from sources with MacPorts [macports]. Enjoy! :-)

[nmap] https://nmap.org/

[zenmap] https://nmap.org/zenmap/

[macports] https://www.macports.org/

Answer (score 3):

Fing (mostly known as a mobile network scanner for android/ios) has a freely available [macos console version](https://www.fing.io/fingkit-sdk-downloads/) which additionally does some fingerprinting via its own built-in mac address manufacturer tables. It appears to be faster than nmap.

Once installed you can run it with:

```bash
sudo fing -r 1
```

<sup>`-r 1` will run the discovery once; without the flag it will keep running the discovery in live mode.</sup>

It is apparently closed source so I don't know how safe it is to use. Make sure you are aware of potential risks.

Also available as a [homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/fing-cli) [cask](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/fing-cli.rb):

```
brew install fing-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

**Works:**

```
$ for ip in $(seq 1 254); do ping -c 1 192.168.0.$ip; done
```

or

```
$ for ip in $(seq 1 254); do ping -c 1 192.168.0.$ip -W 1; done
```

**Description:**

```
loop from 1 till 254
on each loop ping the ip one after another, to skip press CTRL + C
or
on each loop -W 1 means auto skip after 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two common protocols by which devices announce themselves on the local network.

One is Bonjour, which is an Apple invention, and has already been answered here (though they're missing the alternative browser [BonJeff](https://github.com/lapcat/Bonjeff/releases).

The other is SSDP (related to UPnP), which comes from the Windows world. It is a bit more verbose. You can use this [SSDP Browser.app](https://github.com/tempelmann/SSDP-Browser/releases/tag/v1.0) (my own work, BTW).

Answer (score -1):

On the Mac, there is [IP Scanner](http://10base-t.com/macintosh-software/ip-scanner/), which looks has a GUI that aggregates arp, bonjour, NBT and some other network scanning technologies.

Comment: Hi! Per the [FAQ], please disclose any affiliation with products you recommend. And please don't let that be the only reason you're on Super User—otherwise your posts may be considered spam.

Comment: IP Scanner is useless as it has a 6 device limit, then they want $30. Avoid this.

Comment: I wasn't sure what to think of this comment at first, and I'm not sure how to see that the author of this answer is affiliated with the product. If they are, they should have definitely disclosed it.

That being said, I checked out IP Scanner and I really like it. Fantastic GUI. Saves me a ton of time. The free version is good enough for me and I can see myself buying the paid version if I use it more often. Looks like money well spent to me.

There used to be a great shareware culture in the old days; IP Scanner is essentially that. I like it.